# Why isn't my etc/cron.d file executing?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

```
*/5 * * * * root ruby /opt/redmine/extra/svn/reposman.rb --redmine-host http://tracker.intranet.****.com.ar --scm Mercurial --svn-dir /opt/repos/hg --command "hg init" --owner www-data --url http://repos.****.com.ar/hg --key=1EV2OGLL2h >> /var/log/redmine_repos.log 2>&1
0 9 * * * root cd /opt/redmine && /usr/local/bin/rake redmine:send_reminders days=7 RAILS_ENV="production"
```

It is not being executed.

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 ene 11 16:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 97 root root 4096 ene  9 20:19 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  510 ene 11 18:09 php5
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  102 feb  9  2013 .placeholder
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root  398 ene 11 19:00 redmine
root@tracker:/etc/cron.d#
```

I had to execute the first line manually, and it succeeded. Any tips on why isn't it running? I copied it from a running Ubuntu 12.04 updated to 14.04.

My SO is Ubuntu 14.04 Server

I know it is not getting executed because the task it should make is not being done and also no log is created.

EDIT:

/etc/crontab:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

Ruby:

```
root@tracker:/etc# which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Any log output from `crond` in the system log? Is `ruby` in the `PATH` configured for `crond`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging Jan 11 18:10:01 tracker cron[938]: (*system*php5) RELOAD (/etc/cron.d/php5)
Jan 11 18:10:01 tracker cron[938]: (*system*redmine) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/redmine). I fixed the permission now, hope it gets executed.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I noticed that message is from an hour ago... no further output. Should crontab files be executable? Because some time ago I was trying to fix it and put exec bit on the files, but then run-parts said there was a Exec format error

Comment: No, `/etc/crontab` need not be executable. You have ignored the second part of my comment.

Comment: @HaukeLaging how can I figure that. PS: my file is named /etc/cron.d/redmine

Comment: Is there a line `PATH=...` in `/etc/crontab`? What is the putput of `type ruby`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I updated my question with the requested info. Thanks

Comment: From http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91202/cron-does-not-print-to-syslog: Try `sudo chmod 600 /etc/cron.d/redmine`

Comment: @DanielAlder Yes the problem were the permissions. Thanks!